# Parse a text file and extract a specific column

Tags: python, file, text

I would like to read values from a text file until that is a float value. Lets say I have the following file:

```
Time  
Detailes
Distance   Fz    Fx.
0.0000   249       4      
0.0002   247      33     
0.0004   246      49     
0.0006   243      61     

Distance   Fz    Fx.
0.0000   249       4      
0.0002   247      43    
0.0004   246      59     
0.0006   243      70
```

And I need only the values under the first Distance column.

So something like skip the first few rows, then read values from the first column while it is float.

Thanks your help in advance

Comment: What have you tried? Stack Overflow isn't here to do you work for you, it's here to help you if you've tried something and run into problems. Let us know what you've attempted and what issues you've run into.

Comment: @dorvak: it's obviously not a csv format.

Comment: Sorry, I explain what I have done so far. This is a txt file, but I decided to convert it to xls and make the algorithm on that. Using the xlrd I did a function like  i=0  while isinstance(sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=0),(int,float))==True : distance.append(sh.cell_value(rowx=i, colx=0))   i = i+1                    It worked but after I had too big txt file to convert them to xls, so that is why I want now directly use txt file to get data

Answer (score 0):

Make a [state machine](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_machine) that will `readline()`/`for line in file` and do things and/or switch state depending on `re.match()` result on regexes corresponding to different lines' formats.

This is the standard approach to parse input that isn't so complex as to require a [lexical analyzer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_analyzer).