# Python: Write matching word starts with number from a line using python

Tags: python, file, text-files

I want to read text file and find the words that starts with 5 in below text.

```
16  16   011000   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8
26  26   011a00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:03
27  27   011b00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:4d:77:c6:07
32  32   012000   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:54:80
42  42   012a00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:01
43  43   012b00   id    N16     Online      FC  F-Port  56:c9:ce:90:12:b4:19:03
```

My output in another file should be

```
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA
```

But when I write to another file, its only writing last word. But i need to write all the words matching.

here is my code :

```
import re
import sys
import os

with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/Status2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file :
        matchedLine = ("\n".join(list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('56'),line.split(' ')))))
                print(matchedLine)

with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(matchedLine)
```

Comment: You should split the line first then take -1 split_line.starts_with(“5”)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [extract data at specific columns in a line if there is any data at them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569908/extract-data-at-specific-columns-in-a-line-if-there-is-any-data-at-them)

Comment: Why is the expected only the words that start with `51` and not the rest that start with `5`? You may want to clarify your question as it doesn't match your wanted output. Also is this just for the port numbers at the end? What if the two digits numbers at the start also start with `5`, would you want to include those?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/Status2.txt', 'r') as file:
    l='\n'.join(i.split()[-1] for i in file if i.split()[-1].startswith('51'))
with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(l)
```

`/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt`:

```
51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8
51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:54:80
```

In your question you wanted the file to be upper, so try this:

```
with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/Status2.txt', 'r') as file:
    l='\n'.join(i.split()[-1].upper() for i in file if i.split()[-1].startswith('51'))
with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(l)
```

`/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt`:

```
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:E8
51:40:2E:C0:01:C9:53:EA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `re` and unpacking:

```
import re
new_data = [re.split('\s+', i.strip('\n')) for i in open('filename.txt')] 
final_results = [a for *_, a in new_data if a.startswith('51')]
```

Output:

```
['51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:53:e8', '51:40:2e:c0:01:c9:54:80']
```

Python 2 solution (without unpacking):

```
final_results = [i[-1] for i in new_data if i[-1].startswith('51')]
```

Answer (score 0):

You're storing the last match in `matchedLine` and overwriting any previous match it stores.

You should store the matches in a list instead and keep adding new matches to it:

```
matches = []
with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/Status2.txt', 'r') as file:
    for line in file :
        matches += list(filter(lambda x: x.startswith('56'),line.split()))

with open('/root/SDFlex/work/cookbooks/ilorest/files/file001.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write('\n'.join(matches))
```

Comment: I see. You should strip the line first before you split, or simply use `split` without an argument. That is, replace `line.split(' ')` with either `line.strip().split(' ')` or `line.split()`. I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Since your format is column-based, the most readable way would be to extract specific columns as per [extract data at specific columns in a line if there is any data at them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569908/extract-data-at-specific-columns-in-a-line-if-there-is-any-data-at-them/45571491#45571491) .

Also do not try overzealously to fit everything into one line -- that only results in unreadable code.

```
with open(<...>) as infile, open(<...>) as outfile:
    for line in infile:    # don't override `file` 'cuz it's a built-in type
        mac = line[56:79]
        if mac.startswith('5'):
            print(line)
            outfile.write(line)
```

---

For a one-off task, `grep` would be good enough:

```
$ grep -P '^.{56}5' infile >outfile
```